# Domain has no mail exchangers

Tags: email, domain

This problem has occurred last week when I was trying to send email as well as waiting email from another person. I have a domain (@k*****s.com), and while I am able to send and receive to/from everybody else, one specific person is unable to receive mine, and send to me (he is also able to send and receive to anyone else. The exact error he receives as he forwarded it to me, is below:

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of 
its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address 
failed:

"****@k*******s.com": 
domain has no mail exchangers

P.S: I use a server with MDaemon installed. It is clean from viruses etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain has to have [MX DNS record(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) pointing to your mail server(s). This is required by RFC 5321, the most recent standard governing this.

Earlier RFCs allowed fallback to A records, and many email servers are lax and will allow mail from domains without MX records. But some are more strict, and will not. So, in short, fix your DNS, or some of your mail will get lost / bounced.

There are more to it, of course. Running an email server on a residential IP address will earn you high spam score in many places, etc. Running a reliable mail service is more complex than just installing an MDaemon or some other MTA.